# TypeError: 'Library' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, typeerror, django-template-filters

I have the following project structure:

```
kjp_app/
templatetags/
   __init__.py
   myfilters.py
```

In myfilters.py I have this code:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register(name='rep_slash')
def rep_slash(value):
    if '' in value:
        return value.replace('','/')
```

In the corresponding html file I loaded myfilters and used `rep_slash` as below,

```html
{% extends 'kjp_app/base.html' %}
{% load myfilters %}
{% block body_block %}
  {% if client_rec %}
    <table>
      {% for rec in client_rec %}
          <tr>
            <td>{{ rec.client_name }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.client_designation|rep_slash }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.client_job_location }}</td>
            <td>{{ rec.client_phone_num }}</td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor%}
    </table>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

I am getting the following error when running the server:

```
File "D:\Django_projects\Pradeep Website\kjp_enterprise\kjp_app\templatetags\myfilters.py", line 5, in <module>
  @register(name='rep_slash')
TypeError: 'Library' object is not callable
[19/Jan/2019 14:57:45] "GET /kjp_app/view_clients HTTP/1.1" 500 151123


I am using Django 2.1.5 and python3.7
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@register.filter(name='rep_slash')
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `filter` after the `@register`. 
This `filter` helps to register a callable as a template filter.

Your function should look like this:

```
@register.filter(name='rep_slash')
def rep_slash(value):
    if '' in value:
        return value.replace('','/')
```

I hope you find this helpful.